# Google OAuth migration: OAuth2 client type does not match OAuth1 consumer type

Tags: google-oauth

I have some existing OAuth 1.0 tokens from Google users, and am attempting to exchange them for OAuth 2.0 tokens, as described [here](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth_ref#migration).

The request to the `/o/oauth2/token` endpoint returns the following error response:

```
{"error": "unauthorized_client",  "error_description" :"OAuth2 client type does not match OAuth1 consumer type."}
```

My OAuth2 key is registered as a web application, so Google must consider my OAuth1 key as a native application. The Google doc page states that an OAuth1 key is considered a native application if either of the following is true:

- The application has set its native application name, or
- The application is a Chrome extension.

I don't have a Chrome extension, and, as far as I know, have never set the native application name (though I can't find any settings page to check this).

Is there some other reason an OAuth1 key would be treated as a native application?

Comment: Could you post some code here.  There isn't currently enough information to help solve this problem.

Comment: Hi, I work in the Google Auth team... looking into this now. Will update this post with my findings before the end of the week

Answer (score 1):

We have made a modification to our migration implementation that should have gotten this kind of failures fixed.

We have also updated the [migration documentation](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth_ref#migration) accordingly.